# Cube Analog Disc vs. Cube Aim Disc

Tags: mountain-bike

I am willing to buy a new bike and I'm stuck between Cube Analog Disc and Cube Aim Disc. What should I go for? What are the advantages of one over another?

I will use this bike on all kind of terrains (meaning city, off-road, mountain, road), but I won't go mountain-biking (in the real word) very often.

Thank you!

Comment: Try http://www.cube.eu/en/service/bike-comparison/. I compared the bikes, and the differences are small, analog seems a bit more expensive and high quality key components (rear derailer and suspension, actually the only different parts between the two models)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences between the bikes are small, and mainly will relate to durability. The quality of several key components is higher on the Analog Disc, which should equal smoother, faster shifting and better longevity of these components.

In addition the Analog Disc is a 9 speed bike, and the Aim Disc is an 8 speed bike. As the current high end models are 10 speed, and 8 speed mountain components are expected to go away in the next year or so, I would recommend the Analog Disc.

They aren't showing pricing, but I wouldn't expect more than a 100-150 dollar or so difference between the 2 bikes.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I went for the Cube Analog Disc bike. Thank you for your tips!